# How safe is it to set a user's role in a redux store and reading from it to conditionally render a certain component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a page that shows details of a certain report and allows either to edit the details, or to finalise it so no more edits can be made to the reports. I have three roles: user, admin, and superadmin. User is the role that creates and edits the reports but only the admins can finalise the report. While most of the components are the exact same for user and admin, only the admins should have the access to the button that finalises the report. What I have done currently is set the user info in a redux state named auth that can be accessed to read the role and then conditionally render some components. I was wondering how efficient/secure it is and if there are better alternatives?

I have stored a JWT for the user's info in a cookie and I have a middleware to check the role of the user on the backend before it allows an update, but I was trying to not render the components which are not allowed to the user role.

This is what I have done right now:
`
const { role } = useSelector((state) => state.auth).userInfo;

```
// other code  

{role === "admin" && (  
    <CustomButton  
        onClick={() => {  
            updateReport({  
                ulr: report.ulr,  
                update: { isAuthorised: true },  
            });
        dispatch(  
            updateReportState({  
                ulr: report.ulr,  
                field: "isAuthorised",  
                value: true,
            })  
        );  
        navigate(// url);  
      }}  
    />  
  )}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

It will be impossible to prevent someone from hacking the front-end to potentially have it render the parts you want to hide based on roles/permissions.  The only way to make that happen would require the server to send different code back to the front-end.  And even then a hacker could still make changes to that code.

However, it's not necessary in my opinion to secure the front-end in that manner.

Have the server alway check the user's authorizations before performing the work on its end.  Of course, this requires the server to be the "source of truth" for all.  If the report is printed and someone expects the printed report to be trustable without checking the state on the server, well that doesn't seem feasible.

So, deciding what content to show on the front-end based on permissions is OK in my opinion - but it is critical that the back-end never send data to the front-end that the user should not have access to view, and the server must always validate the data send to it from the front-end against the user's permissions.